# Dealing with Race Conditions when making Fetch requests in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, shopify

For anyone that has a decent understanding of Vue.js, I have a question. I work for a company that uses a Shopify theme along with Vue.js for their front end.

I am currently working on a feature that requires me to render an **Add to Cart Button** or an **Out of Stock Notification** on a product page depending on how close a customer is to a specific fulfillment center (where our products are shipped from) and how much of that specific product is present at that time.

It geolocates the customer and then matches them to the closest fulfillment center and then checks the amount of stock available for that product. If it is available I need to show the **Add to Cart Button** and if it is not available I need to show an **Out of Stock** notification

But the issue is that since this is a regular Shopify website that reloads data on every page, the DOM for the vue template I am using is built before the fetch requests involved in this feature get the chance to finish.

This is some example code from my Vue Component:

```
<script>

    import ProductAddToCart from "./ProductAddToCart.vue";
    import ProductOutOfStockForm from "./ProductOutOfStockForm.vue";
    export default {
        name: "product-action",
        template: "#product-action",
        data() {
            return {
                customerZipCode: null,
                fulfillmentCenterData: null,
                variantInStock: false,
                dataLoaded: false
            };
        },
        components:{
            ProductAddToCart,
            ProductOutOfStockForm
        },
        props: {
            productId: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            currentVariantId: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setCustomerZipCode (){
                //Goal: set customer zip code in component data
                const locationData = this.$root.getCustomerZipCode()
                this.customerZipCode = locationData
            },
            async setFulfillmentData(){
                //Goal: Make request to Private Shopify App for Fulfilment center data
                const productId = this.productId
                const privateAppUrl = "https://7b5a-2603-7000-c400-b62-b85b-19a8-6631-334f.ngrok.io"
                const requestUrl = `${privateAppUrl}/shopify/product-stock/${productId}`

                const request = await fetch(requestUrl, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        customerZipCode: this.customerZipCode
                    })
                })

                const data = await request.json()
                this.fulfillmentCenterData = data

            },
            setVariantInStock(){
                //Goal: Find location product variant by id in array and return true if in stock
                const currentVariantId = this.currentVariantId
                const variantLocations = this?.fulfillmentCenterData?.variantLocations
                
                if(variantLocations && Array.isArray(variantLocations)){
                    const variantFromData = variantLocations.find(locationObj => {
                        if (locationObj.variantId == currentVariantId){
                            return locationObj
                        }
                    })

                    // console.log("Location", variantFromData)
                    this.variantInStock = variantFromData.availability > 0 ? true : false   
                }
            },
            addToCart(data, source) {
            //Emits an event to trigger the add to cart method in the root component inside Theme.js
            console.log("Data inside of ProductAction", data)
            if (this.subscriptionOption) {
                data.selling_plan = this.sellingPlanId;
            }
            this.$emit("add-to-cart", data, "Product Page");
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.setCustomerZipCode()
            this.setFulfillmentData()

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setVariantInStock()
            }, 2000)
        },
        updated(){
            if(this.fulfillmentCenterData && this.variantInStock){
                this.dataLoaded = true
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

You can see from the code that I have a specific method to set the customer's zip code (A String) and the fulfillment data (An Object) for the component. But now here comes the issue I am having.

The 1st problem is that in my method called `setVariantInStock` it depends on data from `this.fulfillmentCenterData` and when I was trying to run it, I run into a race condition problem.

The value for `this.variantInStock` is used in the template for this Vue component as part of a `v-if / v-else` statement to determine whether to render the **Add to Cart Button** or the **Out of Stock Notification**.

You can see that I used `setTimeOut()` to have the method wait until the data from `this.fulfillmentCenterData` is set but I think this is a pretty sloppy way of dealing with this problem.

I tried looking up a good way to deal with this issue as it comes up pretty often on everything that we build or work on.

You'll also notice that I tried to use a data properly called **dataLoaded** to switch over to a value of true in the updated Life cycle hook but that didn't really work on for me either because the Vue reactivity was not triggering for me.

**The only other potential solution I thought of was to set the value of variantInStock inside of a the same method that sets the fulfillment data after the promise resolves but I'm not experienced enough to know if this is the best way forward.**

Anyone have any ideas on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with async function `setFulfillmentData`, so you should await it, then you can remove `setTimeOut`

```js
async mounted() { // It's better to use beforeMount while fetching data for component
    try {
        this.dataLoaded = false;

        this.setCustomerZipCode()
        await this.setFulfillmentData()
        this.setVariantInStock()

        this.dataLoaded = true;
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this and come back and comment with how it went